# recording of each word in a text file in c

Tags: c, string

I am trying to build a function that will check if the word is in a list of words, if it is, it will increment the corresponding counter for the frequency of that word. Otherwise, it will create a copy of the
word and append it to the list. Then set the corresponding frequency counter to 1. 
I get no compiler errors but when I attempt to print the frequency of any word I get a number in the 2 millions and I have no idea why.
I am given a main file I cannot modify:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_WORDS 300
#define LINE_LEN 80

void increment_word_freq(char *freq_words[MAX_WORDS], int *frequency, int *n, char *word);

int main(){
    char delim[] = " ,.!-;\"\n";
    char filename[] = "cookbook.txt";
    char line[LINE_LEN];
    char *word;
    char *freq_words[MAX_WORDS]; // a list of frequent words
    int frequency[MAX_WORDS]; // frequency of the words
    int n = 0; // number of words in the list
    int min_occr;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!fp){
        printf("Could not open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    // read one line at a time
    while(fgets(line, LINE_LEN, fp)){
        // get the words from the line
        word = strtok(line, delim);
        while(word != NULL) {
            // convert the word to lowercase
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
                word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
            increment_word_freq(freq_words, frequency, &n, word);
            word = strtok(NULL,delim);
         }
    }
}
```

this is the function I am attempting to use:

```
void increment_word_freq(char *freq_words[MAX_WORDS], int *frequency, int *n, char *word){

for(int i=0; i<MAX_WORDS; i++){
    if(freq_words[i] == word){
        frequency[i]++;
        break;
    }
    else if(i=MAX_WORDS-1){
        frequency[i]= *word;
        *n++;
    }
}
}
```

like I said before, no compiler errors but attempting to print the frequency of any word will give a number in the 2 millions and I have no idea why.
Any and all help and advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `==` does not do what you expect for strings. Use `strcmp()`.

Comment: We are not supposed to solve your homework. However, pay attention to how string comparison works (do not use ==, this will compare pointers, not contents). Also, your for limit is always `MAX_WORDS`, even though you probably expect it to be `n`, according to your `else` branch. Last, but not least, you are inserting new words each and every time at the same index in the array: `MAX_WORDS-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`freq_words[i] == word` only compares the pionter `freq_words[i]` with the pointer `word`. You have to campare the strings the pointers refer to. Change your code to `strcmp(freq_words[i], word) == 0`. Apart from this you have to allocate dynamic memory to stroe your strings. Use `strcpy` to copy a string int the dynamic memory. You have to do so, because `word` is a pointer to a `char` somewhere in `line`, but `line` will be overwritten if you read the next line of the file. Adapt your code like this:

```
#include <string.h> // strcmp, strcpy

void increment_word_freq( char *freq_words[MAX_WORDS], int *frequency, int *n, char *word)
{
    for ( int i=0; i < *n; i++) // for all current members of freq_words
    {
        if ( strcmp( freq_words[i], word ) == 0 ) // test if word is member of freq_words
        {
            frequency[i]++; // increment count
            return;         // finished, because word was found 
        }
    }

    // word was not found in freq_words => add new word to freq_words 
    if ( *n < MAX_WORDS-1 ) // test if there is one more place in freq_words
    {
       freq_words[*n] = malloc( strlen(word) + 1 );   // allocate dynamic memory for new meber of freq_words
       strcpy( freq_words[*n], word );                // copy word to freq_words[*n]
       frequency[*n] = 1;                             // int frequency[*n] with 1
       (*n)++;                                        // increment count of members of freq_words
    }
}
```

Note you have to `free` the allocated memory at the end of `main`, otherwise you have memory leaks.

```
for ( int i=0; i < *n; i++)
{
    free( freq_words[i] );
}
```